# Problems configuring an application in Facebook (website with Facebook login)

Tags: facebook, heroku, web-hosting

all:

We have a software developer building a web site with Facebook login for our company. They have told us to register a Facebook application.

For the moment, the beta application is hosted in a development environment. I would like to start testing also the Facebook integration. But when I access to the application page in Facebook, I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXOmd.png).

I think it might be related to an attribute I find in the first page of the app configuration. The attribute is called "[Hosting URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcuQv.png)".

The option seems to be linked to some kind of hosting service provided by Heroku. I don't know exactly what is that, but I would say we do not need it. We will use our own hosting server and, what's more, our application is developed in a language different that the one Heroku supports.

Could somebody confirm us which is the problem and, if it is possible, give us a hint to solve it?

Thank a lot in advance,
-The SportPoket team

---

Comment: Have you put the right URLs into the “App on Facebook” settings?

Answer (score 1):

The "Hosting URL" is meant to be the public web address of your finished production application. During development however, you only need to provide the URL for the app that is accessible from your web browser. If you are running a local web server on port 5000, `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` will work.

Heroku is just one of the suggested hosting services for Facebook and you don't have to use it, but the documentation can be helpful. More about setting up a Facebook app dev env can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#1-creating-a-development-facebook-app